# Issue with React and depth of props

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I don't know why this is happening. When I try to setArray  to a data.map, React complains and I have no idea why. Here are the codes of key components. I've also tried to move the useState hook into the 's parent element and passing it as props but I got the same error
[image]

**My Data Component:**

```
export let DataContext = createContext();

export let DataProvider = (props) => {
  let [array, setArray] = useState([]);
  let [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      name: "Toshiba",
      desc: "Laptop copmuter",
      price: 299,
      url:
        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3975677/pexels-photo-3975677.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940",
      path: "Toshiba",
      type: "laptop",
      details:
        "Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space",
    },
    {
      name: "Lenovo",
      desc: "Laptop copmuter",
      price: 399,
      url:
        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3975677/pexels-photo-3975677.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940",
      path: "Lenovo",
      type: "laptop",
      details:
        "Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this spaceSome words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space",
    },
    {
      name: "Asus",
      desc: "Laptop copmuter",
      price: 199,
      url:
        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3975677/pexels-photo-3975677.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940",
      path: "Asus",
      type: "laptop",
      details:
        "Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space",
    },
    {
      name: "HP",
      desc: "Laptop copmuter",
      price: 299,
      type: "laptop",
      url:
        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3975677/pexels-photo-3975677.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940",
      path: "HP",
      details:
        "Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space  Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space ",
    },
    {
      name: "Apple",
      desc: "Laptop copmuter",
      price: 299,
      type: "laptop",
      url:
        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3975677/pexels-photo-3975677.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940",
      path: "Apple",
      details:
        "Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this spaceSome words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space",
    },
    {
      name: "Apple",
      desc: "Android",
      price: 299,
      type: "mobile",
      url:
        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/3975677/pexels-photo-3975677.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940",
      path: "Apple",
      details:
        "Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this spaceSome words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space Some words just to fill this space",
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={[data, setData, array, setArray]}>
      {props.children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
```

****My Item Component that I get error on: ****

```
function Item() {
  let [data, setData, array, setArray] = useContext(DataContext);

  let newAr = data.map((item) => {
    return (
      <div className="Item">
        <img src={item.url} />
        <h1>{item.name}</h1>
        <p>{item.desc}</p>
        <h2>{item.price}</h2>
        <Link to={`/product/${item.path}`}>
          <h3>See details</h3>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  });

  setArray([newAr]);

  return <>{array}</>;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not do

```
  setArray([newAr]);
```

inside the component as it is. It needs to be done or in event handler, or in useEffect hook.

Right now, you just recursively updating component.  Component renders - component updates newAr - it gets signal set newAr is updated - it rerender components - component updates newAr - etc
It falls in a never ending loop.

try

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setArray([newAr]);
  }, [])
```

This will update newAr only when component is mounted.

P.S. It is no a good approach to store React Nodes in the state.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issues with the the main error but now I got "TypeError: setArray is not a function" inside my handleClick function.

 P.S.    What do you mean by storing React Nodes in the state, where did I do that? (Pardon my ignorance, I'm sill a beginner with React)

Comment: newAr is an array of JSX nodes. It is not data. The common approach is to store data inside state/context/redux, but nodes to be calculated on flight, or cached with useMemo. Because react does diff between prev data and new data in order to decide which part of DOM needs to be updated. If stay with you approach - it will be diff between JSX, which becomes React.createElement at the end. Do not mix data and JSX. JSX should not be compared by react, it should be only rendered,